# how to update image ,keep image same if user do not upload and update if uploads

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i want to update image in edit panel,i have displayed uploaded image name there ,if user uploads then no problem code is working fine but if do not uploads still the image upload code is working and showing me invalid file type.please tell me what is the problem .

please suggest enhancement for the code

```
 if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{

if($_FILES['image']['type']=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES['image'] 
['type']=="image/jpg" || $_FILES['image']['type']=="image/png")
     {

         $imgname=$_FILES['image']['name'];
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image'] 
['tmp_name'],"recent_upcoming_img/".$_FILES['image']['name']);


         $imgquer="select fimage from $table where date='$date'";
        $imgres=mysqli_query($conn,$imgquer);
        $r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($imgres);
        $preimg="recent_upcoming_img/".$r['fimage'];
        unlink($preimg);





         $quer="update $table set 
  title='$title',content='$content',fimage='$imgname' where 
    date='$date'";
          $res=mysqli_query($conn,$quer);

         if($res)
         {

         unset($_SESSION['table_e']);
         unset($_SESSION['date']);
         header("Location:dashboard.php");
         }
          else{
         header("Location:edit.php");
          }

   }

            else
           {
               $imgname=$_FILES['image']['name'];
               echo '<script language="javascript">';
               echo 'if(alert("INCORRECT FILE TYPE ")){} ';
               echo 'else{window.location = "edit.php"}';
               echo '</script>';
           }

      }
       else

      {



       $quer="update $table set title='$title',content='$content' where 
      date='$date'";
         $res=mysqli_query($conn,$quer);

         if($res)
         {

         unset($_SESSION['table_e']);
         unset($_SESSION['date']);
         header("Location:dashboard.php");
         }
          else{
         header("Location:edit.php");
          }





     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the file is not uploaded **$_FILES** will return an empty array (As below)

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Change the if condition as below

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name']))
{

// Write your codes here

}
```

Comment: @MOHIT BHAT Upvote and accept the answer if it helps you